# use finite element method to solve the PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, finite-element-method

Hi so I want to use the finite element method to solve this question
∂/∂x (y^2  ∂u/∂x (x,y))+∂/∂y (y^2  ∂u/∂y (x,y))-yu(x,y)=-x      (x,y)∈D
where the boundary conditions are:
u(0,y)=0 for 0.5 ≤y ≤1 and u(x,0.5)=2x, for 0≤x ≤ 0.5 on S1
y^2  ∂u/∂x (x,y)cosθ_1+y^2  ∂u/∂y (x,y)cosθ_2=√2/2 (y-x) on S2
compute the solution for (0,1) and (0.25,0.75)
I already divided the domain into  two triangular elements:
T_1: (x_1, y_1)= (0,0.5),(x_2, y_2 )= (0.25,0.75),and (x_3, y_3 )= (0,1)
T_2: (x_1, y_1 )= (0,0.5),(x_2, y_2 )= (0.5,0.5),and (x_3, y_3 )= (0.25,0.75)
and the shape functions for element T_1 are:
N_1 (x,y) = 2-2x-2y
N_2 (x,y) = 4x
N_3 (x,y) = 1-2x+2y

and the shape functions for element T_2 are:
N_1 (x,y) = 2-2x-2y
N_2 (x,y) =1+2x-2y
N_3 (x,y) = -2+4y

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).